# In asp.net core not playing hls

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, http-live-streaming

I have Blazor server project for test how to play hls video. I created the video using ffmpeg (test.m3u8 and list of .ts files) and it plays without problems using VLC.  To avoid Cors Policy error all video  I load to  wwwroot/3D folder.  Additinally I try this .m3u8 file

> https://res.cloudinary.com/dannykeane/video/upload/sp_full_hd/q_80:qmax_90,ac_none/v1/dk-memoji-dark.m3u8

with the same result

```
I use this code :
```

_hosts.cshtml :

```html
@page "/"
@namespace TestHLS.Pages

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<base href="~/" />

<script src="~/js/video.min.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/js/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/js/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

 <link  href="~/js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

 <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {     
        var player = videojs('my-video');
        player.play();
    });
</script>
```

Index.razor:

```html
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>


 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>


 <video id="my-video"  controls   
     muted="muted"
     autoplay="autoplay">  
     <source src=@videoSrc type="application/x-mpegURL"  />
     Your browser does not support the video tag
 </video>    

 @code{
  string videoSrc = "http://localhost:5293/3D/test.m3u8";     //string videoSrc = "http://localhost:5293/3D/bbk.mp4"; 

}
```

and program.cs:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using TestHLS.Data;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("NewPolicy", builder =>
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}


app.UseStaticFiles();


var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

provider.Mappings[".m3u8"] = "application/x-mpegURL";  //application/x-mpegURL

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});

var fileProvider3D = new PhysicalFileProvider("D:/3D");
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider3D,
    RequestPath = "/3D",
});


app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("NewPolicy");

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Now I see the initial image and get an error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted because the media was removed from the document.

How to solve an issue?

Comment: Hi А.Терентьев, could  you share an  update on this issue. I am willing to help if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Using below code, then you can play `.m3u8` file normally.

[image]

```
@page "/test"
@model BlazorApp1.Pages.TestModel
<PageTitle>Test Page</PageTitle>

<!-- Video.js CSS -->
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Your view content starts here -->
<div class="container">
    <h2>Test M3U8.</h2>
    <div>
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{}'>
            <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dannykeane/video/upload/sp_full_hd/q_80:qmax_90,ac_none/v1/dk-memoji-dark.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Video.js JS and HLS plugin -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-contrib-hls@5.15.0/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Video.js -->
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var player = videojs('my-video');
        player.play();
    });
</script>


@{
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the problem did not solve. Depending on the browser type, it either gives the specified error or does not, but only shows the initial frame. At the same time, if you do not insert a tag into the video   " muted="muted"  autoplay="autoplay"" it gives an error     "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."  Perhaps the problem is related to the OS Windows server 2008R2, I'll try it on Windows 10.

Comment: Same situation under Windows 10. If you run it for the first time, then the error does not occur - the first frame is simply shown. When restarted, an error occurs. To avoid the impact of the cache, I change the version in the project settings, then the error does not occur.

Comment: The frame appears for a moment and disappears